# RoR install showing w/o images on local host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

New to rails and trying to get everything up and running. Working through railstutorial.org and can see that a local install should look like this:

http://railstutorial.org/images/figures/riding_rails_3-full.png

But instead looks like:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/peteralderson/6890785887/in/photostream

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: what's wrong ? It's just an HTML page you need delete it in real life. So what care ?

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the new "[asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)" added in Rails 3.1.

The reason the image isn't showing up could be caused by multiple things -

Is the server running in development or production mode? (Development compiles assets on the fly, production assumes they have been pre-compiled.)
Do any messages appear in the server log relating to "rails.png"?

Comment: Thanks - I'll try and look into the production vs. development mode.

Comment: You'd probably know if it was running in production mode - you'd have to start it explicitly with "rails s -e production". The default is development.

Comment: Go to your app directory and try this command - "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"  That generates compiled versions of any assets (images/css/javascript) into the public/assets directory.  Not sure why you'd have to do this in development mode though...

Comment: Running locally in development. In running the server, the reference to .png is as follows:

Comment: Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Feb 18 06:37:45 +1100 2012 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'

Comment: Those errors sound like the database isn't running/configured... what database are you using? SQLite? MYSql? What does your Rails app's `config/database.yml` have in it?

Answer (score 0):

Its a default rails home page. It shows your local configured environment when you click on link about your applications environment. You need not to do anything whit this page. In place of this page you need to set your default home page. And yes there is nothing wrong with the installation.

Comment: Thanks - but I want to make sure the environment is correct before I go any further. I can see the ruby HTML page that should be displaying on the public folder but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Simply means Rails has changed from what you have in the tutorial, try to check up the new things with the version of rails you have on your machine, best is to ensure you are using the same version of rails from the tutorial in practice else you might end up confused

Comment: That's not it - I can see the file in the folder that should be displaying.

Comment: Are you sure you have not implemented any styling framework e.g blueprint???